# ASP.NET Web Application - Unhandled exception in Bootstrap.js: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, bootstrap-4

I'm currently working on an ASP.NET Web Application project and encountering JavaScript errors related to jQuery and Bootstrap. Specifically, I'm facing two distinct issues:

"JavaScript critical error in https://localhost:44383/Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.js\n\nSCRIPT1010: Expected identifier"

"Unhandled exception in https://localhost:44383/Scripts/bootstrap.js
0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery"

However, when I run the project, I encounter the mentioned JavaScript errors. The first error, related to jQuery, states "Expected identifier" in the jquery-3.4.1.js file. The second error, related to Bootstrap, throws an unhandled exception in the bootstrap.js file, with the message "Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery."

In my HTML or layout files (e.g., _Layout.cshtml), I have included the JavaScript files in the correct order, with jQuery being loaded before Bootstrap:

```
`@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)`
```

while in my BundleConfig files (e.g., BundleConfig.cs)

```
`public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        //"~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.js"));

            // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
            // ready for production, use the build tool at https://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                       // "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));
                        "~/Scripts/modernizr-2.8.3.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                      "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                      "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                      "~/Content/site.css"));`
```